# UITableViewCell width not expanding on rotation to landscape

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm having trouble resizing the content of a `UITableViewCell` when the device rotates to landscape (and therefore view width increases).

[image]
[image]

For context, this is part of a universal split view app and is only occurring on iPhone 8 in the simulator (which doesn't support split view). Later devices which do support the split view have no issue.

In my `UITableViewController`, `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, and 'Follow Readable Width' is unchecked in IB. I have also added:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The `tableView` also has a custom `UITableViewCell` to which I've added:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   uniqueIDLeading.constant = (self.contentView.frame.width * 0.4)

   layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

No errors or warnings in the console. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have auto-layout constraints added?

Comment: Yes I do, based on the UITableViewCell content view

Comment: If you have used autolayouts then this would not be happen. Please share the code of UITableViewCell to understand the context properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually fixed with the following in custom `UITableViewCell` class.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar issue today, but I am not using a custom cell. I solved it with the following code.

Swift:

```swift
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
```

Objective-C:

```
self.tableView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, and I'm sure in yours, I forgot to call a super class method.

```
open override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    .......
}
```

Comment: Please don’t post duplicate answers.

Comment: @soundflix, I don't agree that this is a duplicate. The rest of the answers focus on flexible Width, but it has nothing to do with it. It's all about super.layoutSubviews(), I'm sorry I couldn't bold this line.

Comment: Look at @Tom‘s own solution: he added `super.layoutSubviews()` to method `layoutSubviews( )`, that’s what you showed.